# Instantiate PagerAdapter Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

2Hi guys I'm trying to build an app using a horizontal pager and the support package for Android. I've made this exact code compile in another project but the last line of the second code example is not letting me compile. Eclipse is saying `Cannot instantiate the type PagerAdapter`

My imports

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

My code

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
```

Do you think there is something wrong with my imports or project set up - let me know if you need more information. This code has worked in other projects.

Thanks

Comment: PagerAdapter is an abstract class, and can therefore not be instantiated. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) is an `abstract` class – you cannot instantiate it. You have to create a new class that inherits from `PagerAdapter` and use that instead.

Comment: I have create a new class PagerAdapter, even though it shows the same error.  @Herrmann

Answer (score 2):

Just create a new class that inherits from `PagerAdapter` and use it instead.

NB: Don't forget to remove the initial import 
"import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;" 
and import the newly created class.